# Returning an array in Python (2.7.12) ctypes: incorrect results in first run, no problem starting from second run

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I have a C++ function that I want you call in Python 2.7.12, looking like this:

```
extern "C" {
    double* myfunction(double* &y, double* &z,
                  int a, int b)
    {
        vector<double> _x;
        vector<double> _y;
        vector<double> _z;

        // Call some external C++ function
        cpp_function(_x, _y, _z, a, b);

        // Convert vectors back to arrays
        double* x = &_x[0]; // or x = _x.data();
        y = &_y[0];
        z = &_z[0];
        return x;
    }
}
```

Basically this function takes as input two integers `a,b` (plus some other data that I omitted for clarity purpose) and do some calculations before putting the results in two arrays `y, z` and returning an array `x` of size `a*b`.

After building this function to a shared library `myfunction.so`, I call it in Python as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('myfunction.so')
myfunction = libc.myfunction

myfunction.argtypes = ()
myfunction.restype = POINTER(c_double)

y = c_double()
z = c_double()

a = 18
b = 18
x = myfunction(byref(y), byref(z), c_int(a), c_int(b))

X = np.asarray([x[i] for i in range(a*b)])
X = X.reshape((a, b))

# print sums over colums and over rows
print('sum over col')
print(np.sum(X, axis=0))
print('sum over row')
print(np.sum(X, axis=1))
```

The sum of each column as well as each row of `X` should be 1.

Running the Python script I obtained:

> sum over col
>
> [1.00000000e+000 1.38691247e-309 1.65267271e-315
>   1.25888994e-315
>    6.28349788e-316 1.44468811e-315 1.00000000e+000 6.30543835e-316
>    1.65486616e-315 6.30543094e-316 4.20365893e-316 1.39823788e-315
>    1.00000000e+000 4.20363294e-316 1.49114498e-315 6.93457613e-310
>    1.00000000e+000 1.28096634e-315]
>
> sum over row
>
> [1.00000000e+000 1.00000000e+000 1.00000000e+000 6.99111970e-316
>    6.99111495e-316 6.99111021e-316 1.00000000e+000 6.93459588e-310
>    3.78325942e-315 2.45135624e-315 3.71670210e-316 5.81849688e-316
>    5.81849807e-316 3.71670210e-316 5.81849925e-316 5.81850044e-316
>    6.93456516e-310 5.30598164e-316]

Running it for a **second time**:

> sum over col
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> sum over row
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

My data and my function are **deterministic**. All runs starting from the second gave the same results. The problem only occurs in the first run (e.g. if I add a comment to the script and run it again then the problem occurs).

**This problem does not occur in Python 3.5.2**. Unfortunately I have to use the function in a Python 2.7.12 environment :(

My question: Is there a solution to this problem?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: `myfunction.argtypes = ()` this is clearly wrong. Check the specs (or other examples on this site) regarding what to put there. Also `double* &y` this looks a bit unnatural.

Comment: @CristiFati Yet it works for me :( I think the problem does not come from here. I tried specifying `argtypes` as `myfunction.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double), c_int, c_int]` and the problem still remains :(
For the C code, `double* &y` means the input pointer (or array) will be modified in the function. It works well in Python 3 so I think there is no problem in the C code. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Even if something works there's no reason to keep it wrong. I know what the *C* code means, I'm just saying... (I would have used a double pointer). Then the 3 vectors are stored on the stack, and will be wiped out when you exit the function, yielding *Undefined Behavior* (or at least, I think so).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. Could you please be more specific on how you would have done? I still didn't get it. By the way, thanks to your comments I realized that I forgot to return the size of `y` and `z` (I didn't notice this as I didn't use `y` and `z` in my Python code).

Comment: I said that I've used `double **y` for example, but I don't think that's relevant. But the problem are the arrays on stack. to correct that you could either declare some `static` vars, either allocate them on heap (but then you'd be responsible to freeing them). Also I don't think passing `byref(c_double())` would do the trick.

Comment: @CristiFati You are right, there is a serious mistake in my code. `y` and `z` should be `POINTER(c_double)` and not `c_double` (because they are arrays). In addition, I'm trying to return the size of `y` and `z` but encountered a problem. I'm writing another question right now.

Comment: @CristiFati Please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204971/python-ctypes-pass-argument-by-reference-error I think it's basic but I could not find an answer anywhere. Thank you for your help!