# Python ctypes: pass argument by reference error

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C++ function that I want you call in Python 2.7.12, looking like this:

```
extern "C" {
    double* myfunction(double* &y, double* &z, int &n_y, int &n_z, int a, int b)
    {
        vector<double> _x;
        vector<double> _y;
        vector<double> _z;

        // Call some external C++ function
        cpp_function(_x, _y, _z, a, b);

        // Convert vectors back to arrays
        double* x = &_x[0]; // or x = _x.data();
        y = &_y[0];
        z = &_z[0];
        n_y = static_cast<int>(_y.size());
        n_z = static_cast<int>(_z.size());
        return x;
    }
}
```

Basically this function takes as input two integers `a,b` (plus some other data that I omitted for clarity purpose) and do some calculations before putting the results into two arrays `y, z` and their respective sizes into `n_y, n_z`, and returning an array `x` of size `a*b`.

After building this function to a shared library `myfunction.so`, I call it in Python as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('myfunction.so')
myfunction = libc.myfunction

myfunction.restype = POINTER(c_double)
myfunction.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double),
                       c_int, c_int,
                       c_int, c_int]

y = POINTER(c_double)()
z = POINTER(c_double)()
n_y = c_int()
n_z = c_int()

a = 18
b = 18
x = myfunction(byref(y), byref(z),
               byref(n_y), byref(n_z),
               c_int(a), c_int(b))
```

Running this script I obtained an error:

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: : wrong
>   type

So the `c_int` type of `n_y` is not correct. What should I put instead?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion by @GiacomoAlzetta and @CristiFati, I have changed my code to use **pointers instead of pass by reference**, as follows.

(`y` and `z` are similar so let me omit `z`)

```
extern "C" {
    double* myfunction(double** y, int* n_y, int a, int b)
    {
        vector<double> _x;
        vector<double> _y;

        // Call some external C++ function
        cpp_function(_x, _y, a, b);

        // Convert vectors back to arrays
        double* x = &_x[0]; // or x = _x.data();
        *y = &_y[0];
        *n_y = static_cast<int>(_y.size());
        return x;
    }
}
```

Now in C++, I call the above function as follows:

```
double* y;
int n_y;
int a = 18;
int b = 18;
double* x = myfunction(&y, &n_y, a, b);
```

which works. And in Python:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('myfunction.so')
myfunction = libc.myfunction

myfunction.restype = POINTER(c_double)
myfunction.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(c_double)), POINTER(c_int),
                       c_int, c_int]

y = POINTER(POINTER(c_double))()
n_y = POINTER(c_int)()

a = 18
b = 18
x = myfunction(y, n_y, c_int(a), c_int(b))
```

which produced a `Segmentation fault` error, which happened at the line

```
*y = &_y[0];
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try a pointer to `int`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta You mean a pointer to int for n_y and n_z?

Comment: Yes. references are "glorified pointers". Given that Python only "speaks C" it is reasonable to expect that you'd have to use a pointer there... but I'm no expert in this regards.

Comment: I don't think that *ctypes* understands *C++*'s pass by reference.That's why you should stick with pointers.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta and CristiFati: Thank you for your comments. I've spent an hour on this but sill failed. Please see the update in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: cc @CristiFati thanks

Comment: I hope your actual code doesn't "Convert vectors back to arrays" like that, because you've got dangling pointers once your vectors self-destruct.

Comment: @user2357112 So sorry for missing your comment!! Could you suggest a better way to "convert vectors back to arrays"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2357112 Mark Tolonen also proposed a way to do this in this excellent answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. 
In the meantime, stay close to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Remember that you should handle pointer arguments (actually it applies to all of them, but for non pointer ones things are straightforward) the same way, no matter where you are.

In other words, what you do in *C* (**instantiate a variable** and **pass its pointer** to the function), you should also do in *Python* (***instead of*** **instantiate the variable pointer** and **pass it** to the function).

Translated into code, you should modify the way you initialize *y*, *n_y*, and the function (*myfunction*) call:

> ```py
> >>> #from ctypes import *  # Anti-pattern. Don't use it
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>>
> >>> y = cts.POINTER(cts.c_double)()  # Instantiate simple pointer
> >>> n_y = cts.c_int()
> >>> a = 18
> >>> b = 18
> >>> x = myfunction(cts.pointer(y), cts.pointer(n_y), a, b)
> ```

**Notes**:

- What I stated in a comment (*Undefined Behavior* because vectors are living on the stack and will be destroyed when exiting the function) still stands. To fix it either:

  - Allocate the data on heap (*malloc* / *new*) before returning it (when done with it, you'll also need to deallocate it (*free* / *delete*), to avoid *memory leaks*)
  - Make them *static*

Some (remotely connected) examples:

- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)
- [[SO]: How can i cast a double pointer ctype to numpy array? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784385/4788546)

Comment: Thank you so much, @CristiFati!!! I sincerely apologize for my very late reply. Before receiving your answer I had to switch to another urgent project and so I really couldn't find the time to test and give feedback earlier. Thank you again for your valuable help!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You can use references, since references are just syntax for yet another level of pointer.

You vectors are local variables and are freed when your function returns, so you need to keep the memory around.

Here's your C++ code reworked to keep the memory around.  I just created some local variables with some data since your example wasn't complete:

```
#define API __declspec(dllexport)  // Windows-specific export
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    API double* myfunction(double* &y, double* &z, int &n_x, int &n_y, int &n_z)
    {
        vector<double> _x {1.1,2.2,3.3};
        vector<double> _y {4.4,5.5};
        vector<double> _z {6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9};

        // Allocate some arrays to store the vectors.
        double* x = new double[_x.size()];
        y = new double[_y.size()];
        z = new double[_z.size()];
        memcpy(x,_x.data(),_x.size() * sizeof(double));
        memcpy(y,_y.data(),_y.size() * sizeof(double));
        memcpy(z,_z.data(),_z.size() * sizeof(double));
        n_x = static_cast<int>(_x.size());
        n_y = static_cast<int>(_y.size());
        n_z = static_cast<int>(_z.size());
        return x;
    }

    // A function to free up the memory.
    API void myfree(double* x, double* y, double* z)
    {
        delete [] x;
        delete [] y;
        delete [] z;
    }
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.myfunction.argtypes = (POINTER(POINTER(c_double)),
                           POINTER(POINTER(c_double)),
                           POINTER(c_int),
                           POINTER(c_int),
                           POINTER(c_int))
dll.myfunction.restype = POINTER(c_double)

dll.myfree.argtypes = POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double)
dll.myfree.restype = None

# Helper function to allocate storage for return arrays
def myfunction():
    y = POINTER(c_double)() # create an instance of a C double*
    z = POINTER(c_double)()
    n_x = c_int()           # and instances of C int
    n_y = c_int()
    n_z = c_int()

    # Pass them all by reference so new values can be returned
    x = dll.myfunction(byref(y),byref(z),byref(n_x),byref(n_y),byref(n_z))

    # Copies the data into Python lists
    a = x[:n_x.value]
    b = y[:n_y.value]
    c = z[:n_z.value]

    # Free the C arrays and return the Python lists.
    dll.myfree(x,y,z)
    return a,b,c

x,y,z = myfunction()
print(x,y,z)
```

Output:

```
[1.1, 2.2, 3.3] [4.4, 5.5] [6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9]
```

Note there is a lot of copying going on.  Look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which creates arrays in a format that can be directly accessed by C and has a built-in ctypes interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! And sorry for my late reply. Since @CristiFati's answer was posted first, I accepted his answer. But your answer is also great so in addition to upvoting it, I found another answer by you and upvoted it as well. Thank you!